Cannot roll back a transaction with CREATE TABLE statement
func main() {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    DoTx(tx, ctx, cancel)

}

func DoTx(tx *sql.Tx, ctx context.Context, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    // Perform first insert
    _, err := tx.Exec("CREATE TABLE `testTable`(`testCol` INT);")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    _, err = tx.Exec("INSERT INTO testTable(testCol) VALUES('1')")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error first insert: ", err.Error())
        return
    }

    // Cancel the context
    cancel()
    // Wait to prevent tx to be executed before ctx.Done is received 
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    // Only proceed if not canceled
    _, err = tx.Exec("INSERT INTO testTable(testCol) VALUES('2')")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error second insert: " + err.Error())
        return
    }

    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

}

Output:
Error second insert: sql: transaction has already been committed or rolled back

And until here everything seems fine except that when I look into the database table testTable has been created and testCol has an entry '1' (first insert).
Shouldn't the whole tx been rolled back?

Which version of Go do you use? Asking because of this https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34775

@raina77ow latest version

Judging by the backticks you are using MySQL. If so, MySQL does not support transactional schema changes. CREATE TABLE implicitly COMMITs. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

@Peter it was that, thank you.

@mirkosailorm Remember to always defer cancel() after creating a context.
